# Cannot call a Bootstrap modal function on a Div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to build a CMS using Symfony in which I am trying to use Vanilla JS instead of jQuery. I am displaying a modal with some info on page load.

If I do `$("#companies").modal();` the bootstrap modal is displayed correctly.

Until now I thought `let companies = $("#companies");` and `let companies = document.getElementById('companies');` were equivalent. But when I tried to call the modal function on the element returned by Javascript `getElementById`, it gave me error `modal() is not a function`.

How can I call the Bootstrap modal function using an element returned by `getElementById` function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use bootstrap without jquery. All js components have jquery dependency. To use bootstrap without jquery, you need bootstrap clone like [bootstrap.native](https://thednp.github.io/bootstrap.native/v4.html)

Comment: I have jQuery included in my project but I just want to minimise its usage in my custom code. I want to display this modal using JavaScript.

Comment: as i said you cannot bootstrap components without jquery. check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/#js

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you could manually do it the Vanilla  way

```
function toggleModal() {
    const yourModal = document.getElementById('companies');
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('modal-open');
    if (yourModal.style.display == 'block') {
        yourModal.style.display = 'none';
        yourModal.classList.remove('in'); 
        document.querySelector('.modal-backdrop').remove(); //remove shadow
        document.querySelectorAll('#companies [data-dismiss="modal"]').forEach((elem, index) => elem.removeEventListener('click', toggleModal)); //remove listeners

    } else {
        yourModal.style.display = 'block';
        yourModal.classList.add('in');
        //backdrop effect
        const shadow = document.createElement('div');
        shadow.classList.add('modal-backdrop');
        shadow.classList.add('fade');
        shadow.classList.add('in');
        document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(shadow);
        //add event listeners for dismissing dialog
        document.querySelectorAll('#companies [data-dismiss="modal"]').forEach((elem, index) => elem.addEventListener('click', toggleModal)
        );
    }
}
```